# how to get windows phone 7 GPS timespan diff

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, time

i'm building a program that does certain operations according to the user's speed. 
is there a way to get total seconds elapsed since last Position_Changed() ?
i guess it's gotta do with the timestamp variable.
but even when i do

```
TimeSpan offset = e.Position.Timestamp - lastTimestamp;
```

i dont know know what to do with the offest variable. is there a way to get total number of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the earth a sphere:

```
x = earthRadius * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude);
y = earthRadius * -sin(latitude);
z = earthRadius * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude);
```

The center of the coordinate system is the center of the earth.

There are [more spherical coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates)